# linq-to-sql "Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached"

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm getting the error `Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.` when I try to delete a record. I've googled around and although there's plenty of places to find the solution to fix this problem, the suggested fix doesn't get me further:

```
using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyDataContext())
{
  TheDC.MyTable.Attach(ARecord); //added this line but doesn't fix it.
  TheDC.MyTable.DeleteOnSubmit(ARecord);
  TheDC.SubmitChanges();
```

My bigger question is this: does this issue ONLY affect delete queries or does it affect other kinds of queries too and I just haven't bumped into this problem yet. I've written an update query and it seems to work without running into this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please refer to this SO Post: [How to delete in linq to sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319981/how-to-delete-in-linq-to-sql)

> ...about attaching, if you already have the primary key. If you don't have the primary key then I have always just done a fetch then a delete, but, whenever I do a fetch I tend to store the primary key for updates and deletes.
>
> It will delete off of the primary key, but if you have that then just attach as I do below and call delete. I don't pass around the object needed by DLINQ as I want to be able to change it if I want, so I pass in a different User object and just pull the PK from the business class and put it into the DAO class.
>
> ```
> var db = new MeatRequestDataContext();            
> if (input.UserID > 0)
> {
>      entity = new User()
>      {
>          UserID = input.UserID
>      };
>      db.Users.Attach(entity);
>      db.Users.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 7):

For me, the fix was just searching for the database object first.

```
var db = new MeatRequestDataContext();
if (input.UserID > 0)
{
    var existing = db.Users
        .Single(user => user.UserID == input.UserID);

    db.Users.DeleteOnSubmit(existing);
}
```

In my mind, I could only delete what was already there, so I needed to go get the items in the database that I wanted to delete first. This also works with collections and DeleteAllOnSubmit().