# Despite attaching the object to context getting the error? can not remove an entity that has not been attached

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i have attached object to context, despite i am getting the error `Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.`

```
if (itemRemove != -1)
{
    //var deleteDetails = DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters.Where(p => p.ProductID == this.ProductID && p.CustomCategoryID == catId && p.CustomType == (short)catTypeId).Single();
    var deleteDetails = DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters.Single(p => p.ProductID == this.ProductID && p.CustomCategoryID == catId && p.CustomType == (short)catTypeId);
    DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters.Attach(deleteDetails);
    DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteDetails);
    RemoveCategoryItems(catId, catTypeId);
}


private void RemoveCategoryItems(int catId, CategoryType catTypeId)
        {
            switch (catTypeId)
            {
                case CategoryType.Topping:
                    (this.ToppingItems.Where(xx => xx.ToppingInfo.CatID == catId && xx.ProductID == this.ProductID).Single()).IsDefault = false;
                    FreeToppingItems.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductID == this.ProductID && x.ToppingInfo.CatID == catId);
                    break;
                case CategoryType.Dressing:
                    (this.DressingItems.Where(xx => xx.DressingInfo.CatID == catId && xx.ProductID == this.ProductID).Single()).IsDefault = false;
                    FreeDressingItems.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductID == this.ProductID && x.DressingInfo.CatID == catId);
                    break;
                case CategoryType.SpecialInstruction:
                    (this.InstructionItems.Where(xx => xx.InstructionInfo.CatID == catId && xx.ProductID == this.ProductID).Single()).IsDefault = false;
                    FreeInstructionItems.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductID == this.ProductID && x.InstructionInfo.CatID == catId);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what query provider are you using?

Comment: Why are you attaching? It is already attached as you never detached it? Where is the error being thrown? In this method or the `RemoveCategoryItems` method?

Comment: You shouldn't need to attach an entity which was retrieved through the service, is the error thrown on the `DeleteOnSubmit()` or when you call `DBContext.SaveChanges()`. What are you using LINQ to access also (SQL, SQLCE, ODATA etc..?) as the implementation is slightly different for each.

Comment: it throws error at this point DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteDetails);

Comment: Try sumbitting the delete *right* after the call to `DeletOnSubmit`, at least for now, to see if it works.  If it does (which it should) then that will tell you that your problem is with some other code somewhere else.  Perhaps you're deleting another item in a completely different place in the same batch that's the source of your actual problem.

Comment: I agree with @Servy. Call Submit just after the DeleteOnSubmit.

Comment: No where i am deleting..

Comment: i see sombody else face the sane problem, but can't infer any thing from it linq-to-sql “Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached”  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611761/linq-to-sql-cannot-remove-an-entity-that-has-not-been-attached

Comment: After this line: DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteDetails);
Call DBContext.SubmitChanges();

Comment: No avail calling submitchanges() same error Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.

Comment: Please try the example in the answer I edited below then. If that doesn't work, there is something else going on with the DBContext in some other section of code where an object is being added to the delete list, but that object isn't attached to the context.

Comment: ok i try and let you know..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35292/discussion-between-novicetodotnet-and-joe-brunscheon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*FIRST IDEA* - You don't need to attach the item that you are going to delete. The item is already attached to the context and the state is being managed. Just skip the attach line and delete the object.

*EDIT* Since the attach doesn't appear to have been your problem, give this a shot:

```
     if (itemRemove != -1)
     {
         var deleteDetails = DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters.Single(p => p.ProductID == this.ProductID && p.CustomCategoryID == catId && p.CustomType == (short)catTypeId);
        //Obviously, this isn't going to work directly, you need to actually assign the ID, Primary Key Field here...
        var deleteMe = new ProductCustomizationMasters() { PrimaryKey = deleteDetails.PrimaryKey };
        DBContext.Attach(deleteMe);
        DBContext.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteMe);
        DBContext.SubmitChanges();

        RemoveCategoryItems(catId, catTypeId);
      }
```

*EDIT AGAIN* - The code you have posted doesn't appear to be the source of your problem. There is something outside of this code that is setting an object up for deletion from the context ant has not been attached. I suggest working back through your code and inspecting all references to "DeleteOnSubmit" and making sure that those entities are attached when you mark them.

Comment: if deattach it then also i was gettign the same error, thats why i managed it like that.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet He never said you should detach it, he said you shouldn't attach it; just do neither.

Comment: yes i skip the line  // DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters.Attach(deleteDetails); but i get the same error Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.

Comment: If you are still getting that error, you might start looking at the RemoveCategoryItems code. Can you post that code in the original question?

Comment: ok but that work on collections. i put it in the questios, i think it dont go even to that method..

Comment: it doesn't allow me to creaqte an object for ProductCustomizationMasters() says could not be found

Comment: Remove the 's' from ProductCustomizationMasters.

Comment: Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.

Comment: actually you were right 2 context were open to database, one somewhere on another page, and i was creaing a new here through which i was manipulating it so the previos one troubling with state maintained.

Comment: Glad you were able to track down the issue!