# Attach newly created element in LINQ for deleting

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have a grid and dataset object connected with it.
And datalayer working with LINQ. So I need to delete elements that was deleted in grid from LINQ data source.

I have a method that convert my DataRow item to LINQ item. For example:

```
DataRow forDelete = ...;
LinqItem itemForDelete = ConvertFromDataRow(forDelete);
dataContext.DeleteOnSubmit(itemForDelete);
```

this code throw an exception, that imposible to delete item who is not attached to table.
But if I change it to

```
DataRow forDelete = ...;
LinqItem itemForDelete = ConvertFromDataRow(forDelete);
dataContext.Attach(itemForDelete)
dataContext.DeleteOnSubmit(itemForDelete);
```

than it will throw exception that it's impossible to attach item, which already exist.

**Question will be how to attach an item properly in that case. That should solve the problem.**

Comment: Did you try Finding the LinqItem, and then Deleting it... like `var object = dataContext.xxx.Where(x => x.ItemId == itemForDelete.ItemId);` and then `dataContext.DeleteOnSubmit(object);`

Comment: Yes, that approach work, but in current situation I can't use it. Because I have generic method and a lot of legacy code. So I can't find element by Id because Linq don't know that my element have an ID field. And I can't inherit it form item who have that field for sure because of great ammount of legacy code, which will be pretty hard to maintain, because all items is autogenerated and have a bit different structure.

Comment: Also, I try to workarounf it using dynamc expression and searching that element in loop, but this approach have a very poor performance.

Comment: Having your database object not in sync with your actual database seems like a bad idea...you really should update the item to actually reflect what that table contains...

Comment: You do not read my question carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are no correct answer on that question or no way to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because you are trying to delete an Untracked item.

Find by Id before DeleteOnSubmit.

more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386982.aspx

and

[How to delete in linq to sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319981/how-to-delete-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: I use generic methods and have no ability to select item by ID because my method do not know that item have and ID. And it's not possib;e to have common basic class for all the enities because of greate ammount of legacy code.